# Creating an Event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have written code that changes the color of a mark the user places on an image (drawn on a Canvas element) based on how long the user holds down the click for. Currently, if the user holds down for less than a second, a blue mark appears; otherwise a green mark appears.

I want to create a way to let the user know that a second has passed since they started clicking, perhaps an indicator panel on the side changes color, etc. I have a timer that starts counting from when you start clicking. How do you create an event that triggers when that timer reaches one second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for something like this,

```
setTimeout("javascript function",milliseconds);
```

The setTimeout() method will wait the specified number of milliseconds, and then execute the specified function.

Comment: The first parameter of `setTimeout` should *never* be a string. Use a function reference.